# Jquery Countdown Smooth Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Is there a way with this script to make a smooth animation ?

By that I mean each intervale removes a chunk of the timer but I just find it to sudden. Is there a way to make it more like it's drawing itself rather than jumping ?

This is the code

```
var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
radius: 60,
seconds: 20,
label: ['sec', 'secs'],
fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
autostart: false,
onComplete: function () {
  console.log('done');
}
});

countdown.start();

$('#countdown').click(function() {
  countdown.extendTimer(2);
});
```

I know I could add something like that but on which element.. ?

```
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: -webkit-transform @transition-length;
        transition: -ms-transform @transition-length;
        transition: transform @transition-length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johnschult/gs3WY/

Comment: This is a `canvas`, you'll have to dig into the `JS` code of `countdown360` to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't think you can without rewriting the code. The code calculates the time and adjusts the circle to match the time. What you want is to know upfront where the next stop is and gradually get there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the internals of the functions that cause full rounding to a second.  So, add this code before the call to countdown.start():

```
// Replace draw function so it rounds to 1/10 of a second
countdown._draw = function () {
    var secondsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime())/1000),
        tenthsElapsed = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt.getTime())/100)/10,
        endAngle = (Math.PI*3.5) - (((Math.PI*2)/this.settings.seconds) * tenthsElapsed);
    this._clearRect();
    this._drawCountdownShape(Math.PI*3.5, false);
    if (secondsElapsed < this.settings.seconds) {
        this._drawCountdownShape(endAngle, true);
        this._drawCountdownLabel(secondsElapsed);
    } else {
        this._drawCountdownLabel(this.settings.seconds);
        this.stop();
        this.settings.onComplete();
    }
 }

// Proxy start function so it uses a smaller time interval
var oldStart = countdown.start;
countdown.start = function() {
    oldStart.call(this);
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(jQuery.proxy(this._draw, this), 100);
};
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9px2xukd/).  Much smoother animation.  You could also add a parameter for what you wanted the interval to be instead of hardcoding 1/10 of a second as I did, using the same two functions.